# Magento 2.3.2 Incompatible argument type

Tags: error, theme, magento2.3.2, command-line, compile

Error in during compilation:

```
6/7 [========================>---]  85% 33 secs 395.0 MiB
Daniels\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Grid\Collection
Incompatible argument type: 
Required type: \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface. 
Actual type: \Daniels\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Grid\connection; 
File: /chroot/home/a4610039/0f13fb0d8d.nxcli.net/html/app/code/Daniels/Cform/Model/ResourceModel/Cform/Grid/Collection.php
```

Total Errors Count: 1

In Log.php line 92:

My sample code:

```
<?php
namespace Daniels\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
  
    /**
     * ID Field Name
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'contect_id';

    /**
     * Event prefix
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'daniels_cform_allcontect_collection';

    /**
     * Event object
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventObject = 'contect_collection';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Daniels\Cform\Model\Cform', 'Daniels\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Problem is incompatibility __construct for Daniels\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Grid\Collection class with extended class.

Comment: Replace this one.
 protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Daniels\Cform\Model\Cform', 'Daniels\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform');
        $this->_map['fields']['page_id'] = 'main_table.page_id';
    }

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Daniels\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'contect_id';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            \Daniels\Cform\Model\Cform::class,
            \Daniels\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform::class
        );
    }
}
```

Or update your construct this:-

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface  $connection = null,
    ...
) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@daniels

Remove `Generated` folder and compare your collection class with default collection class.

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Directory/Model/ResourceModel/Country/Collection.php

or confirm with below class.

```
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Daniels\Cform\Model\Cform', 'Daniels\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform');
        $this->_map['fields']['page_id'] = 'main_table.page_id';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your __construct in the collection file like below :

```
public function __construct(
    EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    $connection = null,
    AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, 
        $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    }
```

Comment: Let me know if any issue in it.